# how to lower kb load on webpages when pulling info from api

Tags: javascript, json, load, api-design, web-performance

I made a weather webpage that uses an API to pull array information and display it on my webpage. It pulls weather data such as conditions, temperature, wind speed, and weather icon images. The code works well. My problem is that I am not supposed to have any web pages over 500kb, and the one that uses the API is using around 3000. Is there a way to reduce kb use? Below is the code I am using. If I write it differently, will it make the kb usage go down?

```
 //json source
 const apiURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?                    
 id=${5604473}&units=imperial&appid=00000000000000000000000000000000`;

 fetch(apiURL)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((jsObject) => {
         //console.log(jsObject);
         document.getElementById('currently').textContent = jsObject.list[0].weather[0].main;
         document.getElementById('high').textContent = jsObject.list[0].main.temp_max;
         document.getElementById('windspeed').textContent = jsObject.list[0].wind.speed;
         document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = jsObject.list[0].main.humidity + "%";
         document.getElementById('windchill').innerHTML = windchill;
         //calculate windchill
         let t = (jsObject.list[0].main.temp);
         let s = (jsObject.list[0].wind.speed);

         if (t <= 50 && s >= 3) {
             document.getElementById("windchill").innerHTML = windchill(t, s).toFixed(0);
         } else {
             document.getElementById("windchill").innerHTML = "N/A";
         }

         function windchill(t, s) {
             let w = Math.round(35.74 + 0.6215 * t - 35.75 * Math.pow(s, 0.16) + 0.4275 * t * 
 Math.pow(s, 0.16));
             return w;
         };
     });
 //forecast
 const forecastURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
id=${5604473}&units=imperial&appid=00000000000000000000000000000000`;
 fetch(forecastURL)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((jsObject) => {
             const forecastweek = jsObject.list.filter(x => x.dt_txt.includes('18:00:00'));
             let day = 0;
             const dayofweek = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

         forecastweek.forEach((x) => {
             let d = new Date(x.dt_txt);
             //console.log(d);
             document.getElementById(`dayofweek${day + 1}`).textContent = dayofweek[d.getDay()];
        
             const imagesrc = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + x.weather[0].icon + '@2x.png';
             document.getElementById(`icon${day + 1}`).setAttribute('src', imagesrc);

             document.getElementById(`forecast${day + 1}`).innerHTML = (x.main.temp);
             day++;
         })    
         });
```

Comment: don't use real ids like your `appid` when you post questions in public

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely your limit of 500kB is reached by just calling the API and loading a few icons. A response for the given API request returns a payload of +/- 16kB and every icon is +/- 2kB large. In total, for 7 days, I would expect a max consumption of 50kB.

To investigate further, I would advice to inspect the network traffic by utilising your browser's developer tools. For the Chrome browser, a clear explanation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network).

Furthermore, is there a reason you are executing the same API request twice (as the example code would suggest)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. I'll check into it. Yes, I'm using the same API request twice because I'm using it for two separate sections on the web page

Answer (score 0):

Just one other thought, check to see if the response has cookies. IMO it should be served by a cookie-less domain.